# How to convert float to system.Collection.generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#

How to convert float to system.Collection.generic.IEnumerable 
The actual problem occurs when I try to iterate through the returned IEnumerable.

[image: Image1]

> Code

```
  private ObservableRangeCollection<ReviewInfo> _rating = new ObservableRangeCollection<ReviewInfo>();
public ObservableRangeCollection<ReviewInfo> Review
{
        get { return _rating; }
        set { _rating = value; OnPropertyChanged("AvRating"); }
    }

 public async Task GetReview()
    {
        var ber_id= berProfile.Id;
        ResponseInfo<ReviewInfo> res = await nsManager.Instance.GetReview(ber_id);
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
            IsBusy = false;
            if (res.IsError == true) 
            {
                await _page.Alert(res.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                if (res.Data != null && res.Data.Count > 0)
                {
                    var temp = res.Data.Average(x => x.Rating);
                    Review.AddRange(temp);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Post your code here, not picture

Comment: Question is rather unclear since you haven't shown any code. But even the screenshot you posted doesn't help much because it doesn't show any types involved.

Comment: While looking into the image I hope that you are trying to pass a float value to a model named as "ReviewInfo".

Comment: Well, it´s unclear how one single `float` should be added to a list of `ReviewInfo`. As you didn´t provide the code for that class I suppose you want to create a new instance `ReviewInfo` whose property `Value` or similar needs to be set to the average value from `res.Data` - but who except you knows?

Comment: Thanks dear but not perfect ans not working

Comment: Please See The Code

Comment: Apart from that your screenshot does not match your posted code you still did not write what a `ReviewInfo` is.

Comment: A `float` is not a `ReviewInfo`, so that's not going to help either.

Comment: Sorry dear my mistake

Comment: @Happy : By looking into the question, I am unclear about the problem.I request you to please post more information about your requirement. i.e what you are trying to do and What that "ReviewInfo" model is.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite unclear as you didn´t provide what a `ReviewInfo` is. However your error is quite clear: you´re trying to add a float to a list of `ReviewInfo`. Of course this won´t work.

From your code I suppose this class has at least a `Rating`-property or field. Assuming you have a list of those `ReviewInfo`-instances you probably want to retrieve that object whose `Rating`-property is the average of all the elements within your list.

If this is the case your solution is simply this:

```
var temp = res.Data.Average(x => x.Rating);
Review.Add(res.Data.First(x.Rating == tmp));
```

However as `Average` returns a `double` it is fairly possible that there´s no element with *exactly* this rating in your list, so it´s better to apply some tolerance. However this goes too far on guessing what you actually want.

Comment: HimBromBeere I am Working in MVVM Review.Add() I not working AddRange

Answer (score 1):

`Review` is a collection of `GogroomCustomer.Models.ReviewInfo`, so you should create `ReviewInfo` object from `temp` by constructor or set via Property (ex: `reviewInfo`), then use `Add` or `AddRange` method:

```
Review.Add(reviewInfo);
```

or

```
Review.AddRange(new ReviewInfo[] { reviewInfo });
```

Comment: Where is your ReviewInfo constructor?

Comment: [Json("rating")]
 public float Rating { get; set; }

Comment: Create new instance of `ReviewInfo` then set `temp` to that instance `Rating` property, then add to your `Review`. Update your code and new error.